# How to use elastic search index used in one application in another application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I have an application with index called `zzz` and I indexed few documents into the index.

```
        string configvalue1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["http://localhost:9200/"];
        var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri(configvalue1));
        var defaultIndex = "zzz";

        **settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
         .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex)
         .MapDefaultTypeNames(m => m.Add(typeof(Class1), "type"))
         .PrettyJson()
         .DisableDirectStreaming();
        client = new ElasticClient(settings);**


        if (client.IndexExists(defaultIndex).Exists && ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["syncMode"] == "Full")
        {
            client.DeleteIndex(defaultIndex);
            client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex);
        }

        return client;
```

Now  in an entire new application, i have to check if `zzz` is existing or not and just use it for some search operation. Do I still have to write everything that is in between `**` in the above code or just connect to the pool and check for index?

Here is my take:

```
        configvalue1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["http://localhost:9200/"];

        var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri(configvalue1));
        settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool);
        client = new ElasticClient(settings);

        // to check if the index exists and return if exist
        if (client.IndexExists("zzz").Exists)
        {
            return client;
        }
```

Just adding to the above question:

I want to implement some condition like this before indexing:

```
Index doesnt exist && sync mode == full  --> Create index
Index exist && sync mode==full           --> Delete old index and create a new
Index doesnt exist && sync mode == new   --> Create index
Index exist && sync mode==new            --> Use the existing index
```

TIA

Comment: You don´t have to create the Default index again. Just check if it exists.

Comment: did you get any error in your approach

Comment: @PandiyanCool no error.. but it is taking some other index and searching..

Comment: @ASN then try to run your search query by pointing particular index

Comment: @PandiyanCool I just followed the below answer and pointed to a particular index and tried. it is still taking another index for searching. u can read my comment below the answer provided by Russ Cam for more information. TIA :)

Answer (score 1):

You would need at a minimum

```
string configvalue1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["http://localhost:9200/"];
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri(configvalue1));
var defaultIndex = "zzz";

var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
 .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

if (!client.IndexExists(defaultIndex).Exists && 
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["syncMode"] == "Full")
{
    // do something when the index is not there. Maybe create it?
}
```

If you're going to be using `Class1` in this application and don't want to specify the type for it on all requests then add

```
.MapDefaultTypeNames(m => m.Add(typeof(Class1), "type"))
```

to connection settings.

With

```
.PrettyJson()
```

this is useful for development purposes but I would not recommend using in production as all requests and responses will be larger as the json will be indented.

Similarly, with

```
.DisableDirectStreaming()
```

again, I would not recommend using this in production unless you have a need say to log all requests and responses from the application side; this setting causes all request and response bytes to be buffered in a `MemoryStream` so that they can be read outside of the client, for example, in [`OnRequestCompleted`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/connecting.html#complex-logging).

[More details on the settings can be found in the documentation.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/connecting.html)

Comment: Hi Russ, it is still taking the old index and fetching data. I'm confused about this.I have a index `postk` with 30000 docs on the server..  I have created another index `zzz` with 3000 documents indexed into that. In another application I have to check if this(`zzz`) index is present or not and if it is present I have to populate the list of all these 3000 documents. But it is still searching data from `postk` index. Is there any way to printout the client and index details and check accordingly? Its working fine when i tried it on localhost but not on the server on which index is created.TIA

Comment: @ASN, there are many ways to check the requests and responses. One way is to log them out somewhere using `OnRequestCompleted` (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/connecting.html#complex-logging). Another way is to use a web debugging proxy like Fiddler to capture traffic from the local machine (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

Comment: Hi Russ.. Thanks for the info. When i run the application is debug mode in Visual studio, every thing was showing fine like the index (`zzz`), uri(`https:/192.168.x.x/zzz`), but the data is retrieved from other index(`postk`). Another interesting this I observed is when i change the `string configvalue1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[https:/192.168.x.x];` to `string configvalue1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[https:/192.168.x.x/zzz];` it is fetching details from correct index(`zzz`). Its even more getting difficult for me to investigate if the server data is wrong or my code is wrong

Comment: I deleted the index(`postk`) with 30000 documents and then ran the application. It is working fine in this case.. it is now retrieving data from `zzz` index and showing only 3000 dcuments